# Official Facebook Connect button as PNG

Tags: facebook

Is there any official Facebook Connect button, as a image file?

There a lot of really different images on the web, with different sizes, different styles (and even colors), different licenses, free and paid. But I believe there should be some official example, as PNG image.

I know that by using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ I can generate HTML and make screenshot, but seems that it's too hacky, and I'm just missing right page. Is it?

[Brand Permissions Center](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php) doesn't have 'Connect' button

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can get the official "Log in with Facebook" button here. ZIP has PNGs for different sizes
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/#brandedlogin

EDIT 26/07/2014: Facebook seems to have removed those image assets. They now suggest you using a Javascript log in button with their button style. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button

[image: New Facebook log in button]

EDIT 21/02/2018: Facebook has updated the guidelines with a new "Continue on Facebook" button image asset

[image: Continue with Facebook button]

Comment: Is there a problem if a use those images instead of the JavaScript?

Comment: I'm gonna find images and use them instead. I don't see a point in loading extra javascript.

Comment: You can use the images above. They are the original PNGs for each size.

Comment: what idiot designed that new version? I can't just stick that next to my login field - nobody will know what it is

Comment: The reason they want you to use the Javascript library is because it contains... tracking information. (Even if your user doesn't login with facebook.) Kind of nasty. 

I'll use an image instead.

Comment: How do you use the Javascript library in a Native app lol?

Answer (score 2):

Would comment on existing answer, but rep... =\

You can still download the icon [here](https://en.facebookbrand.com/assets/f-logo/). I guess they've dedicated a separate domain to it now. I believe they will always have to provide you with an icon alternative since they require, just as google does:

> The "f" Logo may be used alone or alongside other social icons. It should be used at equal size to neighboring icons. Be sure to maintain its shape and proportions and provide adequate clear space between logos.

You can't really do this consistently without a proper icon.

Answer (score 0):

Sept 2023 Updated

Those trying to locate the official design pack for Facebook can find and  download them through Meta here:

- https://about.meta.com/brand/resources/facebookapp/logo/

You can read about the User Experience Design requirements on the Facebook developer site. Just know that the logos mentioned in the design guide point to a Resource Center that is no longer available.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/userexperience